# Silverlight modal popup to overlay specific container

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

I have "MDI-like" interface which looks like toolbar, tabs and actual views. I'm using PRISM for view injection and so on.

Here is a problem I'm facing.. I need to show modal popups/dialogs throughout application. There is some solutions for PRISM, but it all boils down to injecting Silverlight Popup control. This works well, problem is that it blocks whole screen.

In my application I need those popups to be "modal" to my injected views. Ok, there is MVVM training in a box http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab5f02f-0c54-453c-b437-8e8d57eb9942
Under MVVM scenarios Karl shows how to do exactly what I want. He does it by overlaying Grid with UserControl. It works great for mouse clicks but I can still tab and hit Enter on buttons and do all this stuff.. How can I block overlayed UI for good while showing popup modal to part of the screen only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did something very similar by [creating a UserControl Popup](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/), and ran into the same issue.

I solved it by setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` on the UserControl to tell WPF that the Popup contents is a separate `FocusScope` from the rest of the form, and I set `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` to make the Tab button cycle through the current FocusScope instead of leaving it when it reaches the end.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good solution. I was thinking about iterating visual tree and disabling all focusable/clickable controls when popup displayed :) Will see how your solution works, it's a good starting point.

Comment: @katit Something to note with my solution is that there is an animation that makes the popup display, and during that brief millisecond it is possible to set focus behind the Popup. I have a later version of the control with the animation based on another DependencyProperty (by default it doesn't execute), but I never updated the blog post.

Comment: Actually, I can't take your solution since there is no FOcusManager in Silverlight. But you gave me and idea on what I should be looking for. I was wondering if there "build in" solutions but I guess if there is issue like that in WPF - Silverlight probably worse and I will have to code around it.